# AWS Workspace with multiple monitors

Tags: amazon-web-services, workspace

I am running 3 32" 4K monitors on my laptop.  When I connect to my AWS Workspace, I want to span multiple monitors.  If I resize the window on one of the monitors, it automatically expands the workspace to match those settings.  if I resize over 2 monitors it no longer responds to the resize.  I know you have to use full-screen mode to have this work but if I do that, it tries to use all 3 monitors and only 2 4K monitors are supported.  How can I tell AWS WS that I only want to use 2 of the 3 monitors when I go to full-screen mode?  The only option I have is, "Full Screen on All Monitors".  When I do this, it locks up because it can't handle 3.